# Pass multiple Promises into Node JS render

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I would like to pass data from 3 different promises into the render function in nodejs to use with pug.

```js
var promise = require('promise');

var statusChart = new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            a.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$status',
                        count: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ], function (err, status) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(status);
                }
            });
        });

        var severityChart = new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            a.aggregate(
            [
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$severity',
                        count: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ], function (err, vuln) {

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(vuln);
                }
            });
        })

        var countChart = new promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            a.count(function (err, count) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(count);
                }
            });
        })

        statusChart.then((message) => {
            console.log(message);
        });

        severityChart.then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });

        countChart.then((item) => {
            console.log(item);
        });
```

The above code works fine and will return my results

```html
[ { _id: 'Medium', count: 6 },
  { _id: 'High', count: 15 },
  { _id: 'Low', count: 1 } ]
[ { _id: 'New', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'Closed', count: 1 },
  { _id: 'In Progress', count: 11 },
  { _id: 'Pending', count: 9 } ]
22
```

Question: how do I pass this data in the render function.

res.render('graphs', {info: statusChart, vuln: severityChart, count: countChart});

When I try it this way I get the following results on the pug side

var results = {"_75":1,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":{"onRejected":null,"promise":{"_75":0,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":null}}};
var status = {"_75":1,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":{"onRejected":null,"promise":{"_75":0,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":null}}};
var total = {"_75":1,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":{"onRejected":null,"promise":{"_75":0,"_83":0,"_18":null,"_38":null}}};

Comment: Use `Promise.all`.

Comment: You really should write a helper function that takes an id, calls `new Promise` and `a.aggrate`, and returns the promise for the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing promises to the info, vuln, and count variables. Those are not resolved at that point. To get this working, do the following

```
....
return Promise.all([statusChart, severityChart, countChart])
       .then(([statusChartVal,severityChartVal,countChartVal]) => {
         return res.render('graphs', {info: statusChartVal, vuln: 
                severityChartVal, count: countChartVal});
       });
....
```

Comment: Promise.all resolves when only all promises are resolved. If any of the promises fail, catch is called. So, add catch block.

Answer (score 0):

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             // Do Something //

```
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            //Do Something //
                         Resolve(true); 
                        });
                 Promise.all(Promise).then((responses) => {
                        resolve({
                            status: true,
                            data: data   
                        });
                 });                    
    }).then((response) => {
        res.json(response);
    });
```